# Informatica code to change the date appended to sysdate for file if 00:00 time crosses

Tags: linux, unix, oracle-sqldeveloper, informatica

I have two workflows. One workflow will generate flat filewith sysdate appended. This file used by second workflow. In case if first wf ran before 12 am CST and second workflow runs after 12 am CST, we need to change the date to sysdate for the file in order for second wf to pickup the file.

Comment: its very difficult to know "if first workflow is running before 12 and second one running after 12". Rather, i think its easier to create a list file for 2nd workflow with file generated from first one.  no matter the name, you can create a list file using a pattern using `ls -1 *pattern*> list_file` command.

Comment: I can say like this if the file generated sysdate-1 then we need to change the file appended date to sysdate.

Comment: then if workflow2 runs before 12 ? So its always a dicey situation. if one day things go wrong, you will be in trouble. its upto you...

Comment: I'd rather have first workflow generate a parameterfile for the second workflow to indicate the right file to be picked up.